Is it possible to add more forward slashes to the Default Web Address in Salesforce Sites?
Navigation : Setup > Sites
As in my screenshot, I tried adding more forward slash(es) but get an error saying
The Default Web Address must be alphanumeric.

The reason why I need these extra directory paths is follow my company's policies on URL best practices.
I also tried adding a custom URL but I need to create a custom domain also which I couldn't find a way to create.
Curious how others have approached this problem?


No and custom URLs won't help you. Redirect URLs could do some of this but they're a very limited and static solution. If your site is receiving these requests via an endpoint where you can attach your custom code (e.g. inbound Apex REST), then the path can be anything your code wants.
